# Clicking the notification tray takes me to the login page

Tags: support, bug

I'm having some trouble with the site; if I try to open the notification tray it takes me to the login page, and when I try to log in with my google account, as I usually do, it claims that my google account is "new to stackexchange". Reloading the page doesn't fix it, either. Obviously I *am* logged in, otherwise I wouldn't be able to post this question, so... I have no idea what's happening here.

This has happened before, but refreshing always fixed it. I am able to do basically everything on the site except open the notification tray; it even offers to let me connect this account to a new stackexchange site.

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for meta, so my apologies in advance if it isn't.

Comment: I think that would be more appropriate to ask on the main meta site. Here, only the EE moderators/users are active, and none can administer the site mechanics, only the site contents. On the main meta, some SO employees are active, and they could do something.

Comment: Password remembering features usually help. Session managers in browsers sometimes hurt with site authentication checks and DNS cache misses or wifi reconnects on a different IP address.  But I don’t get these issues. If you use WIFI try moving a bit to ensure you aren’t in a dead spot like FM at some stoplights near tall buildings (Ricean Fading Signal/packet/frame losses)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen before, if you clear out your browser (cookies and cache) then it seems to go away.

Answer (score 0):

And of course, as soon as I ask someone for help, the problem fixes itself. Isn't it always the way, with IT things?

Comment: No, of course not.  However, the unthinking can be fooled into seeing patterns of unusual occurances because they don't notice the usual.  Engineers should understand enough about statistics to not fall for these uncontrolled experiments and anecdotal "evidence".

Comment: That was meant to be a joking observation on how this seems to happen fairly often. I understand the way statistics work and I understand that that was a coincidence. Engineers are allowed to have a sense of humor!